# Upgrade a specific Linux Kernel Subsystem?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, i2c

Is it possible to upgrade only a specific sub-system, say I2C, of the Linux Kernel.

For example:
Is it possible to include "Support for multiplexed I2C bus topologies (introduced in Kernel 2.6.36)" in the Kernel version 2.6.31.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible.

A kernel module or 'subsystem' (eg the i2c module) is build for a specific kernel image, you cannot combine different kernel(module) versions.

If you are feeling lucky (depending on your kernel skills), you could:

1. download the source code of your kernel
2. Install compiler and friends
3. add the updated ic2 driver
4. Try to compile the module for your kernel version
5. Cross your fingers and load it into your own kernel...\

I do not have any experience with this, so I do not know whether this works or not. Of course, if the ic2 module requires other (updated) modules, you could be ending up with updating (almost) the complete kernel...